# Getting Typerror trying to convert Object values to Integer or Datetime Value Year

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This is the dataframe

[image]

The column movie_df["year"] was created from extracting values from the title column:

```
movie_df["year"] = movie_df["title"].str.extract("(\d+)")
```

Line of code

[image]

Error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python `int` is a function that converts a string to an integer. So when you pass it you are actually passing a method as the error describes. From the documentation of pandas, it looks like `.astype` takes a string as an argument. For example:

```python
movie_df["year"].astype("int32")
```

Documentation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Comment: I tried it but get the following error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'method'

Comment: That's the same error you were getting before isn't it? Can you show me what your updated code is that produced this same error?

Comment: Please note: the year column is created from the from the title column. I just extracted the values from the titles.

Comment: I'm a little confused what you are saying, can you give more context of the code by editing your question?

Comment: Ah I think you are misunderstanding. Its okay that the contents of `movie_df["year"]` is a string as that is what extract does. However, you are passing `int` to `.astype` which as I explain in my answer is NOT allowed as `int` is a function. You need to pass the type to `.astype` as a string no matter what the underlying value is as otherwise pandas will not be able to work out what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I first converted the column movie_df["year"] from type object to  string type and used the str.astype(int) to finally convert it to int! That was quite daunting :-)!